# Leer http status en el lado del cliente

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Cómo puedo leer el status del http en el lado del cliente usando JavaScript?, planteando el siguiente caso...

server.js [Usando nodejs | back]

```
res.status(200).redirect('/dashboard');
```

script.js [JavaScript | front]
Esto es lo que quiero hacer, pero de esta manera no funciona, alguien tiene alguna solución?

```
if (http.status == 200) {
    Swal.notify({
        title: "Welcome",
        text: "You have successfully logged in",
        type: "success",
        timer: 3000,
        showConfirmButton: false,
    });
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente `http`? El status lo puedes leer facilmente `fetch(url).then(res => console.log(res.status))`. Nota que se lee antes de convertir la respuesta en json. Lo de node es irrelevante.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un usuario entre en la web mediante el redirect /dashboard, se muestre una notificación si el status es 200 u otra si es 300 por ejemplo

Comment: Me ha servido lo del fetch(url), subelo como respuesta :), muchas gracias @JaimeMenéndez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes leer el `estado` de la respuesta a una petición utilizando la propiedad `status` de la respuesta. Por ejemplo:

```js
fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api")
   .then(res => console.log(res.status))
```

Nota que si utilizas la `API` de `fetch`, el status se lee antes de convertir el cuerpo de la respuesta a `json`.